# MeteorJS source code from deployed app

Tags: meteor

I have deployed app using Meteor UP to ubuntu server on digital ocean 
and have lost the source code (hard disk crash).

Is there any way to retrieve back the source code ?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't help you now, but for future reference I store code in the "cloud" (such as skydrive or DropBox, etc.) for just such eventualities.
As to getting the source code back, there are services that can resurrect data from crashed, and even smashed, hard drives, but whether this is practical for you ($$-wise) is a question only you can answer.
OTOH, sometimes losing your "source code" forces you to do it over and refactor it better than it ever was; remember the fire that destroyed John-Boy Walton's novel?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that, unfortunately, this is not possible, or at least entirely possible to retrieve the source code unspoiled. When an application is deployed using MUP, that is generated as nodejs in a single file.

You can try recover some files on server and redo the project structure. Source files on server after a `mup deploy` are located to : `/var/opt/`.

Good luck !

---

You should consider using version control system like Git : [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)